# Font Scaling in NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using Nativebase throughout my application.

If user changes the Font Size from device settings, all the fonts gets Huge/small. I don't want the font size impact on My app. How can I stop this font size scaling.

In React Native, we have **Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling=false;**
but it is not working for NativeBase.

Please let me know if there is any alternative.

I am using below versions :

```
"native-base": "^2.3.5",
"react": "16.3.0-rc.0",
"react-native": "0.54.3"
```

Comment: How are you using it , can you add the code for that?

Comment: You have raised this on NativeBase github here https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1800

So check this for answers